# Finding handler for query in QueryBus with Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, generics, castle-windsor, cqrs

I try to create application with CQRS and implement QueryBus. There are my queries: generic and one specific query with handler

```
public interface IQuery<TResult> { }

public interface IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult> where TQuery : IQuery<TResult>
{
    TResult Execute(TQuery query);
}

public class PeriodPlanListQuery : IQuery<object> { }

public class PeriodPlanListQueryHandler : IQueryHandler<PeriodPlanListQuery, object>
{
    public object Execute(PeriodPlanListQuery query)
    {
        return new { };
    }
}
```

I use Windsor Castle for resolving dependencies

```
        container.Register(
            Component.For<IQueryHandler<PeriodPlanListQuery, object>>()
                .ImplementedBy<PeriodPlanListQueryHandler>()
                .LifestylePerWebRequest());
```

There in my implementation of QueryBus method

```
    public TResult Send<TResult>(IQuery<TResult> query)
    {
        var handler = _container.Resolve<IQueryHandler<IQuery<TResult>, TResult>>();
        if (handler == null)
            throw new NotSupportedException(query.GetType().FullName);

        var result = handler.Execute(query);
        return result;
    }
```

I got error missing component, my question is what is wrong my implementation of QueryBus or registration in component

> No component for supporting the service
>   Domain.IQueryHandler`2[[Domain.IQuery`1[[System.Object,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], JP.Planner.Domain, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[System.Object, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
>   was found

Comment: The answer to your question is given in this [blog post](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92). Take a look at the `QueryProcessor` implementation and the description of why it is implemented the way it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `PeriodPlanListQueryHandler` is registered to expose `IQueryHandler<PeriodPlanListQuery, object>` but you're trying to resolve a `IQueryHandler<IQuery<object>, object>`.

Both ends need to match exactly for this to work.

Right now your model cannot work so it it may need to be readjusted. I'd suggest forget Windsor for a moment and try to work it out in just plain C# with no libraries.

The current code is effectively trying to do:

```
IQueryHandler<IQuery<object>, object> h = new PeriodPlanListQueryHandler();
```

That is not valid C# and will not compile, and that's also why your Windsor configuration doesn't work as you expected.

Try to figure out a model that meets your needs outside of Windsor, and then it should be fairly straightforward how to configure Windsor for that model.

Comment: How should I change resolver in QueryBus to keep generic injections?

Comment: It depends on the context of your app. I updated the answer with some extra pointers